# How do I get the taxonomy term ID from its name?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

The only function on the [list of taxonomy.module functions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/7) that looks like it does what I want appears to be a private function ([_taxonomy_get_tid_from_term](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/_taxonomy_get_tid_from_term/7)).

What function am I supposed to use if all I know is the taxonomy term name and I need to find out its ID?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's [taxonomy_get_term_by_name()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name) which you use as in the following code.

```
$term_array = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('Foo');
$term = reset($term_array); # get the first element of the array which is our term object
print $term->name;
```

Comment: That seems to give me an array rather than a TID. `$foo[0]->tid` doesn't do anything because it returns an array keyed with TIDs. So to get the TID I need the TID, or to do a `foreach()` even though it's only on one item? Otherwise: `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: It returns an array as there is nothing preventing multiple terms from having the same name. You can't know it's only one item.

Comment: @beth, either use the second parameter to limit to a particular vocabulary, or loop through with `foreach ($terms as $term)` and check the `$term->vid` to make sure you have the right one.

Comment: I just quickly typed in the D6 version that I am used to.  I see now from your links/urls included that you are running D7.  The comments above should clarify things for you.

Answer (score 22):

[`taxonomy_get_term_by_name()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term_by_name/7) will do the trick:

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($row->field_term_name);
if (!empty($terms)) {
  $first_term = array_shift($terms);
  print $first_term->tid;
}
```

Comment: There is also a second argument that got added to Drupal 7 to limit this to a particular vocabulary.  This eliminates the need to loop through the results to find the term you want when you may have multiple tids that share the same name.

Comment: Missing semicolon in the line `$first_term = array_shift($terms);`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a Drupal 8/9/+ answer, designed as a static PHP class method:

```
  /**
   * Utility: find term by name and vid.
   *
   * @param string $name
   *   Term name.
   * @param string $vid
   *   Term vid.
   *
   * @return int
   *   Term id, or 0 if none.
   */
  public static function getTidByName($name = NULL, $vid = NULL) {
    if (empty($name) || empty($vid)) {
      return 0;
    }
    $properties = [
      'name' => $name,
      'vid' => $vid,
    ];
    $terms = \Drupal::service('entity_type.manager')->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadByProperties($properties);
    $term = reset($terms);
    return !empty($term) ? $term->id() : 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This function worked for me:

```
/**
 * Return the term id for a given term name.
 */
function _get_tid_from_term_name($term_name) {
  $vocabulary = 'tags';
  $arr_terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocabulary);
  if (!empty($arr_terms)) {
    $arr_terms = array_values($arr_terms);
    $tid = $arr_terms[0]->tid;
  }
  else {
    $vobj = taxonomy_vocabulary_machine_name_load($vocabulary);
    $term = new stdClass();
    $term->name = $term_name;
    $term->vid = $vobj->vid;
    taxonomy_term_save($term);
    $tid = $term->tid;
  }
  return $tid;
}
```

If you are using another vocabulary (different from Tags), then modify in the code above the line:

```
$vocabulary = 'tags';
```