# How to get taxonomy term name from tid?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

A lot of our stuff has uris formatted like `site/taxonomy/XX`,  where XX is an integer.

I found a lot of questions like "*how to get the TID from the name?*", but I'd like to get the name from the `TID`. I'm trying to put together a breadcrumb script and everything is great except for these cases where I'm getting a trail like "`home > term`". Instead I want to have it like "`home > <TERM NAME>`".

How can I do so?

Comment: Great answers. 

Only for info: For those who want to do the opposite - i.e. get tid from term name, there is a Q&A for that too: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36594/how-do-i-get-the-taxonomy-term-id-from-its-name Hope this is helpful as Search Engines when looking for answers don't seem to understand the ordering of what one needs in terms of 'from' and 'to'.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If you're using Drupal 7 you can use [`taxonomy_term_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7)

```
$term = taxonomy_term_load($tid);
$name = $term->name;
```

If you've got a bunch of term IDs you can save having to run a single query for each load by using [`taxonomy_term_load_multiple()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load_multiple/7):

```
$tids = array(1, 2, 3);
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple($tids);

foreach ($terms as $term) {
  $name = $term->name;
}
```

If you're stuck using Drupal 6 you can use [`taxonomy_get_term()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_term/6):

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term($tid);
$name = $term->name;
```

There's no multiple-load option for Drupal 6 that I know of unfortunately.

Comment: thank you very very much wish i could extra plus for the version support :D

Comment: additional question: I think this along the same lines, is it pretty easy to set it so the urls read site/<term name> ? or would i have to set that for each individual term?

Comment: You can do it on a term-by-term basis but that's pretty laborious. The [pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) was written just for this sort of situation, you can use it to define patterns to auto-assign aliases to terms/content/users/etc.

Answer (score 13):

In Drupal 8, you can get the name of taxonomy terms this way:

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->load($tid);

$name = $term->label();
```

Or to load multiple:

```
$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadMultiple($tids);

foreach($terms as $term) {
  $name = $term->label();
}
```

Comment: I get this error - Notice: Undefined property: Drupal\Core\Entity\Plugin\DataType\EntityReference::$target

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The following function returns the name of a taxonomy term based on its tid:

```
function get_term($tid) {
  return db_select('taxonomy_term_data', 't')
  ->fields('t', array('name'))
  ->condition('tid', $tid)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
}
```

Comment: It's not advisable to use database functions when you can achieve the same thing with an API function.

Comment: In some case it's better to use database function because the API functions load a big volume of data

Comment: Also useful when taxonomy access permission modules restrict access

Answer (score 3):

> For D7:

```
$term = taxonomy_get_term_by_name($term_name, $vocab_name);  
  foreach($term as $key => $data) {  
    $tid = $data->tid;  

    dpm($tid);  

  }
```

> For D8:

```
$term_name = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load(2)->get('name')->value;  
dpm($term_name);
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to obtain the name of the term in Drupal 8 in the following way:

```
//Obtain the term.
$tid=1;
$term= taxonomy_term_load($tid);

//get the field name
$term->label();

//or
$term->get('name')->value;
```