# Are breadcrumbs not working properly?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I am using the following PHP code in the view's header to set the breadcrumbs of the view.

```
global $base_url;
$path = $base_url . "/tag/" . arg(1) . "/" . arg(2);
$title = ucfirst(str_replace("-", " ", arg(2)));
drupal_set_title($title);
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l($title, $path);
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
print views_embed_view('article_tag_name', 'default', array(arg(2)));
```

In my page, the breadcrumbs contain the term ID, not the term name. How do I get the term name?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your breadcrumb is working properly but you get the real path instead of the path alias. You can use [drupal_get_path_alias](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_get_path_alias/7).

`$breadcrumb[] = l($title, drupal_get_path_alias('taxonomy/term/'. arg(2)));`


Seems like you are setting title and breadcrumb in a .tpl file? Try to avoid that and put your logic in template.php.
Quick tip: views_embed_view can cause performance issues.

Comment: i want term name insted of term id.but it shown term id.in my view in argument i put Taxonomy: Term ID.and in basic setting>header a php code.but it's showing term id not term name can you tell me relly good for this.........

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/37827/get-taxonomy-term-name-from-tid

Comment: how to put this into this
<?php
global $base_url;
$path = $base_url."/tag/".arg(1)."/".arg(2);
$title = ucfirst(str_replace("-"," ",arg(2)));
drupal_set_title($title);
$breadcrumb = array();
$breadcrumb[] = l('Home', '<front>');
$breadcrumb[] = l($title, $path);
drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumb);
print views_embed_view('article_tag_name', 'default', array(arg(2)));
?>

Comment: Using the path alias still isn't ideal because it will generally be lower case with punctuation and small words removed. Use taxonomy_term_load() to get the term and then $term->name to get the proper name. Also, this is more functionality than design/visual so it would be better in a custom module than in the theme. But either is better than in the views UI.

Comment: I agree it is a horror debugging php code in fields!